# Exchange 2003 preview of mails of another mailbox by supervisor without marking emails as read

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-web-app, permissions

Is there a way to attach mailbox in Outlook or thru OWA so that supervisor can see the content, monitor user how he/she handles the business with clients without marking the emails as read so they can be processed as normal emails by user? Management want to check how the newly employed people contact clients (users will be notified about possible reading of the emails that they send).

Maybe setting some appropriate access rights on Exchange mailbox would be able to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Using software like [Email Archiving](http://www.policypatrol.com/email-archiving-exchange.htm) from Red Earth. Great solution. I believe other companies like GFI have one as well. You simply can read everything employees produce with access rights to things you grant access too. It isn't free, but isn't super expensive either.
2. Using 2 outlook profiles in Outlook. One with normal account and profile, and 2nd with additional mailboxes you would like to monitor but ... with Read Marking disabled. This option is set per profile so you can't use it in your main profile since you would then have all your mails unread or at least it would be painful to mark item as read. But in case of other employees mailboxes it should work very well.

Hope someone will find this useful :-)